# How to transfer Python objects between processes without resorting to serialization?

Tags: python, memory, serialization, multiprocessing, sharing

I am working on an open-source Python library that is meant to handle [efficient and secure transfer of Python objects over the Internet](https://github.com/MISTLab/tls-python-object).

At the moment:

- (In a separate thread) the library pickles the user's object (or uses their custom serializer),
- It sends the serialized object locally to a background process via localhost TCP,
- The background process does some processing and handles Internet transfer of the serialized object,
- On the target machine, the background process receives the serialized object, does some processing, and transfers it via local TCP to the main process,
- Finally, the main process of the target machine deserializes the object (in a separate thread).

This approach works, but not as nicely as I would like it to.

In particular, when sending and receiving big objects, I noticed that serialization and deserialization are computationally intensive operations that I would like *NOT* to happen in the main process, in order not to slow the user's main down. Instead, I would like serialization and deserialization to happen in the background process. Thus I would need a way to pass arbitrary objects from one process to another without resorting to computationally intensive operations such as serialization.

Is there any reasonable way of achieving this in Python please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you expect this to work without serialization?

Comment: So just consider a simple list with a single `None` in it. `[None]`. You can't just send over the raw memory representation, because that involves a pointer to a singleton `None` instance, it would be jibberish in another process with its own address space.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't know really, something similar to passing a pointer in shared memory in C/C++ but I believe there is no such thing in Python, so I would just like to know whether a clever solution I have not thought of exists (edit: this was to answer your first comment)

Comment: you cant pass a pointer between two programs in c usually either ... certainly not on separate machines ...

Comment: @YannBouteiller you can't pass a pointer between processes in `C/C++` either. What you can do in languages like C is work with things like primitive data types and primitive structs, so you can send a raw binary representation and it can be meaningful, although, care has to be taken (e.g. endianess etc). But as soon as it involves a pointer to some other struct/primitive data type, you can't

Comment: So I think the answer is "there is no way". Now, you may consider, depending on your specific case, alternative, faster serialization formats, but that may not be tractable in your particular use-case

Comment: @JoranBeasley the question is about sharing memory on the same machine, sorry if that is not clear

Comment: OK, wait, in shared memory sure. There is some limited support for working with shared memor yin the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects  (see the note about pointers!) but it is going to basically be limited to ctypes-like things. Perhaps that's one approach that would work, but it isn't going to work in general, so you may want to add more specifics to your question. But this won't work for *arbitrary* objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok I feared so, thank you

Comment: If the purpose is making sure the main process is responsive, what you want may be achievable with *threads* instead of processes. Python threads are not the greatest due to the GIL, but they might be enough to prevent UI freezes, which it sounds like is your goal?

Comment: @mbrig thanks, actually this is already how the library works, but I noticed that deserialization of big objects in its own thread does slow the main thread quite a lot

Comment: Which pickle protocol version are you using? Highest might be faster and not the default.

Comment: I am using the default at the moment, thanks I will give it a try

Comment: within threads you can just pass objects .... you don't need to serialize any mutable object that is changed in a thread should be viewable in the other thread ,,,

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes, as I said this is already how the library works. The issue is that threads in Python are single-core and thus the serialization/deserialization operation that is needed to send the object to the background process (and ultimately to the other machine) slows down the main thread quite a bit for big objects.

Comment: @YannBouteiller this may or may not work for your case, and I don't quite have time to implement and test it, but you could *maybe* do something with a [remote manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager). The thing is, for the manager to work, you'll still need to transfer the class definition over but if the class definition is small, vs the instances of the objects, then maybe that will help? The workflow would basically be: receive object, extract type, send type to main process, which registers it so manager will work, send obj via shared mem

Comment: But "transfer the definition over" is a lot easier said than done. It sounds like what you're library is trying to do is maybe similar to [pyro](https://pyro5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ? I'd look at what they do.

Comment: It is true that pyro probably does something similar since they have these "cloud" instances of python objects, you're right I'll look at their code, thanks.